# setting new column values per group based on condition in sql

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

i have recently started working with sql and i'm working on a table with 3 columns. The table is as follows :

```
| indv | number | flag |
|:----:|:------:|:----:|
| 2477 |  7612  |   1  |
| 2477 |  7850  |   0  |
| 2477 |  7862  |   0  |
| 2477 |  7952  |   1  |
| 2477 |  8150  |   0  |
| 2477 |  8280  |   0  |
| 2477 |  8301  |   1  |
| 2560 |  7612  |   0  |
| 2560 |  7850  |   0  |
| 2560 |  7862  |   0  |
| 2877 |  3422  |   1  |
| 2877 |  3423  |   1  |
| 2877 | 5612   |  1   |
| 2877 | 6123   |  1   |
```

i want to write a query which creates a new column based on grouping by indv values and values in the flag. Like for example, for group 2477 a new column number1 is created such that its value is equal to default number (lets say 10000) if flag is 0 for every entry in a group but equal to first value of a group if flag is 1. However, if difference between number for 2 consequetive flags = 1 is greater than 50 then number1 column will have to have the value corresponding to the latest flag=1 value in the number column. It may seem confusing so have also provided a sample output:

```
| indv | number | flag | number1 |
|:----:|:------:|:----:|---------|
| 2477 |  7612  |   1  | 7612    |
| 2477 |  7850  |   0  | 7612    |
| 2477 |  7862  |   0  | 7612    |
| 2477 |  7952  |   1  | 7952    |
| 2477 |  8150  |   0  | 7952    |
| 2477 |  8280  |   0  | 7952    |
| 2477 |  8301  |   1  | 8301    |
| 2560 |  7612  |   0  | 10000   |
| 2560 |  7850  |   0  | 10000   |
| 2560 |  7862  |   0  | 10000   |
| 2877 |  3422  |   1  | 3422    |
| 2877 |  3423  |   1  | 3422    |
| 2877 | 5612   |  1   | 5612    |
| 2877 | 6123   |  1   | 6123    |
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Thanks for editing, john. Will take care of it in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery :

```
select t.*,
       coalesce((select t1.number
                 from table t1 
                 where t1.indv = t.indv and t1.number <= t.number and t1.flag = 1 
                 order by t1.number desc
                 limit 1
                ), 10000
               ) as number1
from table t;
```

Different databases have a different flavor to limit the rows, so you need to change the `subquery` accordingly.